# Forward declaration just won't do

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

Below are two fragments (ready to compile) of code. In first fragment in which I'm using only forward declaration for a struct while deleting pointer to this struct from a Base class dtor for a Guest class isn't invoked.
In the second fragment when instead of forward declaration I use full definition of this Guest class using delete in Base works ase intended.
Why? Why does it make a difference? Isn't forward declaration suppose to be just a note for a compiler saying that the definition of this class/struct is somewhere else?
I'm very surprised that it just doesn't work intuitively.

```
//First just forward dclr  
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

struct Guest;

struct Base
{
    Guest* ptr_;
    Base(Guest* ptr):ptr_(ptr)
    {
        cout << "Base\n";
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        cout << "~Base\n";
        delete ptr_;
    }
};

struct Guest
{
    Guest()
    {
        cout << "Guest\n";
        throw std::exception();
    }
    Guest(int)
    {
        cout << "Guest(int)\n";
    }
    ~Guest()
    {
        cout << "~Guest\n";
    }
};

struct MyClass : Base
{
    Guest g;
    MyClass(Guest* g):Base(g)
    {
        cout << "MyClass\n";

    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        cout << "~MyClass\n";
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        Guest* g = new Guest(1);
    MyClass mc(g);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

//Second - full def

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

struct Guest
{
    Guest()
    {
        cout << "Guest\n";
        throw std::exception();
    }
    Guest(int)
    {
        cout << "Guest(int)\n";
    }
    ~Guest()
    {
        cout << "~Guest\n";
    }
};

struct Base
{
    Guest* ptr_;
    Base(Guest* ptr):ptr_(ptr)
    {
        cout << "Base\n";
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        cout << "~Base\n";
        delete ptr_;
    }
};



struct MyClass : Base
{
    Guest g;
    MyClass(Guest* g):Base(g)
    {
        cout << "MyClass\n";

    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
        cout << "~MyClass\n";
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try
    {
        Guest* g = new Guest(1);
    MyClass mc(g);
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should make your base class constructors virtual in both cases.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Dear, you can't make a constructor virtual in C++ :)

Comment: @Armen: Words ... smoke and mirrors. It was so clear in my mind. (For those who wonder, it should be *destructors*)

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: Naturally. That's why there's a smiley there. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Informally: the compiler needs the class definition in order to delete the object correctly, because it needs to know how to call the destructor and/or `operator delete` for that class.

Formally, 5.3.5/5:

> If the object being deleted has
>   incomplete class type at the point of
>   deletion and the complete class has a
>   non-trivial destructor or a
>   deallocation function, the behavior is
>   undefined.

You'd be OK if (for example) `Guest` was POD, but you gave it a destructor, so you're not OK.

Answer (score 16):

From the C++ standard (5.3.5/5):

> If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undefined.

So you cannot use delete on your incomplete type. It would call the destructor and the compiler is not yet aware of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't delete the Guest unless you know its definition. It's destructor won't be called.
Also, if Guest has defined a custom operator delete, it would be ignored.

Comment: No, a declaration is enough. A forward declaration won't do, though.

Comment: @kotlinski - `class X { void f(); };`  this is the definition of X whereas `class X;` is the declaration

Comment: Since f doesn't have any body in your example, X is not fully defined.

Comment: @kotilnski: I am afraid you are quite wrong: X is a complete type now. X's definition is there. However X::f is not yet defined, but just declared. A class may be defined even if some of its members are not

Comment: @kotlinksi: terminology check. This is a class declaration: `class Foo;`, a.k.a a forward declaration. This is a class definition: `class Foo { void foo(); };`. It is also a declaration, because every definition is a declaration, and it contains a declaration of member function `foo`. As Armen says, the class definition completes the type `Foo`. This is a definition of the function `foo`: `void Foo::foo() {}`. It is not part of the definition of the type `Foo`.

Comment: OK - this is what "The C++ Programming Language" says: "The construct class X { ... }; is called a class definition because it defines a new type. For historical reasons, a class definition is often referred to as a class declaration."  Both wrong?

Comment: @kotlinksi: C++PL is right. In the sentence you quote, it doesn't mention that `struct Guest;` is *also* a declaration, but is not a definition. So when you say that the declaration is needed, in fact the *definition* is needed. Not all declarations are definitions, so having a declaration is a necessary but not a sufficient condition in this example.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot delete a pointer to an incomplete type. Delete is one of the operations which requires the type to be complete. HTH

Answer (score 2):

The type of `ptr_` is incomplete when you invoke `delete` on it. This leads to undefined behavior. So your destructor may not be called. You can use [Boost.checked_delete](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/utility/checked_delete.html) to avoid such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

(The stdafx.h header is not standard c++.)
If I compile with g++, the compiler generates:

```
 warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator:
 warning: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct Guest’
 warning: forward declaration of ‘struct Guest’
 note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined.
```

Configure your compiler to compile at proper warning and error levels.

Comment: int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])  <- this is also not standard